# Delegate not respond - how to debug

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, childviewcontroller

I create a delegate on my view controller, this is my code:

### **FirstController.h**

```
@protocol FirstControllerDelegate;

@interface FirstController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id< FirstControllerDelegate > delegate;
@end

@protocol FirstControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) delegateMethod:(Testo *)testo;
@end
```

### **FirstController.m**

```
@synthesize delegate; 

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)]) {
  NSLog(@"respond ok");
  [self.delegate delegateMethod:item];
}
```

---

### **SecondController.h**

```
@interface SecondController : UIViewController < FirstControllerDelegate >
```

### **SecondController.m**

```
self.firstController = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil];
[self.firstController setDelegate:self];

- (void) delegateMethod:(Testo *)testo
{
    NSLog(@"%@",testo);
}
```

The problem is that the delegate does not respond to the selector.

The `FirstController` is added as the `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController` that is added as a `childViewController` of `SecondController`.

I use this way for delegate other times and I don't have any problem!

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that you haven't actually set `delegate` when calling `[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)]`, result in in a `nil` call which returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I find the error, that is a stupid error, from this controller I push another controller of the same type, when I push the new control I don't set the delegate, I set it on th first controller but not into the second, now it work!